# How to override luabind class __finalize method?

Tags: class, scripting, lua, luabind

How to override luabind class **__finalize** method?

Trying to do this in such way:

```
class A
function A:__init()
end
function A:__finalize()
end

local original_finalize_function = A.__finalize
A.__finalize = function(...)
  -- some custom logic
  if original_finalize_function then
   original_finalize_function(unpack(arg))
  end
end

local a = A    
a = nil

collectgarbage('collect')
```

But lua still calls only original finalizer. It does work for __init method however:

```
local original_init_function = A.__init
A.__init = function(...)
 if original_init_function then
  original_init_function(unpack(arg))
 end
end
```

Also I've tried to override getmetatable(A).__finilize. Doesn't help too.

How can I override it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but does finalize just go to `__gc`?

Otherwise try iterating over the metatable to try and find out what luabind is doing: `for k , v in getmetatable(myobject) do print(k,v) end`

Comment: Don't know. __finalize is called before __gc. I've tried to override it, but got a crash. From lua reference: "__gc ... (can be set from the C side only)."

*Metatable for class:* __index, __newindex, __luabind_classrep(true), __gc, __call.

*Metatable for object (class intstance):* 1, __eq, __mul, __pow, __index, __call, __unm, __concat, __len, __newindex, __lt, __div, __tostring, __luabind_class(true), __gc, __le, __sub, __add